# Auto copy data in Textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

When loaded data in textbox and I want auto copy this data in textbox then will paste to another textbox. Below is my script, but it is not reach as my request.

var stringValue = document.getElementById("Price").value;

```
    document.getElementById("Price").onkeyup = function ()
    {
        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById("copy_Price").value = stringValue + this.value.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/\d\d\d(?!$)/g, "$&,").split('').reverse().join('');
        };
        

    };
```

Comment: why you are using the windows.load inside your onkeyup function?

Comment: If remove windows.load then it also still not okay

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to copy entered data from the first element to next element on every keyUp events!

so this is the elements

```
<input type="text" id="Price" />
<input type="text" id="copy_Price"/>
```

and the correct script described in bellow

```
<script>   
    document.getElementById("Price").onkeyup = function ()
    {
        var stringValue = document.getElementById("Price").value;
        document.getElementById("copy_Price").value = stringValue;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Mr. Hamid Jolany: If don't use .onkeyup in this case which I also want auto copy entered data then how?

Comment: I don't understand what you want actually! describe more pleas. in this case you have to fire an event to delegate an data copy function.

Comment: It mean that, the copy_Price will auto get data from Price when the Price has already loaded the data inside the textbox. after that we just use onkeyup to change data in Price then copy_Price will auto has data from Price.